# How to make the header take up the full width in a media query?

Tags: css, header, media-queries, width

I wrote the media queries for smaller screens ,but i can not seem to make them work for ipads. I have a problem with the width of the header and the navbar. They don't seem to take up the full width even though I wrote margin and padding 0 (as an asterisk). The max-width of the html is 1600px. Here is a [Print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rARBn.jpg).

```
    <header>
    <div class="Header-TopContainer">
        <div class="Header-MyAccountItem">
            <i class="fas fa-user account "></i>
        </div>
        <div class="Header-MyAccount">
            <a href="#">My Account</a>
        </div>

        <div class="Header-CartItem">
            <i class="fas fa-cart-plus cart"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="Header-Cart">
            <a href="#">Cart</a>
        </div>

        <div class="Header_CheckoutItem">
            <i class="fas fa-check-circle check"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="Header-Checkout">
            <a href="#">Checkout</a>
        </div>
        <div class="Header-VerticalLine"><img src="./Images/first%20hr.png" alt="vertical line"></div>
        <div class="Header-Search"><i class="fas fa-search" id="search"></i></div>
    </div>

    <div class="line mqtablet">
        <img src="./Images/long.png" alt="vertical line">
    </div>

    <div class="Header-LogoContainer mqtablet">

        <div class="Header-LogoText">
            <h1>Car<span style="color:#ff3448">Store</span></h1>
            <p class="Header-LogoSubText">Best Car Seller</p>
        </div>


        <div class="Header-Phone">
            <div class="Header-PhoneIcon">
                <i class="fas fa-mobile-alt mobile"></i>
                <h2>+123 456 7890</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="Header-PhoneNumber">
                <p class="Header-WorkingHours">mon-fri:8:30am-7:30pm; sat-sun:9:30am-4:30pm</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Header-container">
            <div class="Header-Wishlist">
                <div class="Header-WishlistVLine vline">
                    <img src="./Images/first%20hr.png" alt="vertical line">
                </div>
                <div class="Wishlist">
                    <div class="Header-WishlistIcon">
                        <i class="fas fa-star wishlisticon"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Header-WishlistText">
                        <a href="#">Wishlist</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="Header-Compare">
                <div class="Header-WishlistVLine">
                    <img src="./Images/first%20hr.png" alt="vertical line">
                </div>
                <div class="Compare">
                    <div class="Header-CompareIcon">
                        <i class="fas fa-car compareicon"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Header-CompareText">
                        <a href="#" class="compare">Compare</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="Header-MyCart">
                <div class="Header-WishlistVLine">
                    <img src="./Images/first%20hr.png" alt="vertical line">
                </div>
                <div class="Mycart">
                    <div class="Header-MyCartIcon">
                        <i class="fas fa-cart-plus cart mycarticon"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Header-MyCartText'">
                        <a href="#" class="mycart">My cart</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<nav class="toggle-menu">
        <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/>
    <ul class="MainMenu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

@media(min-width:768px) and (max-width:1024px) {

```
header {
    position: relative;
    height: 17rem;
    text-align: center;

}

.Header-TopContainer,
.Header-Phone {
    display: none;
}


.mqtablet {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;

}

.Header-LogoText {
    margin: 0.5rem;
}

.line {
    position: absolute;
    top: 9rem;
}

.Header-container {
    margin-left: 10%;
}

.vline {
    display: none;
}

nav {
    text-align: center;
}

ul {
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    padding-right: 9rem;

}

ul li a {
    padding-left: 5rem;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the media query code that you've used?

Comment: Please also share the header section HTML code.

Comment: Have you added the viewport meta tag inside the `head` tag? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: Yes i have, it works on the other media queries breakpoints . Also everything works on all media queries except the header width doesn't go all the way to the end.

Comment: Have you tried using element selector on your browser (F12 in chrome)? Or maybe some image is too large and goes out of screen?

Comment: Yes is have used it . The print screen is from the F12 in chrome. Up to this point i don't have images on the page.

Comment: Are those the only styles used for header or there are more selectors to it? Nothing seems to be horizontal for me with the styles you have posted.